# Listing all the Users/Group, there Type, UserName, and Permissions

Tags: 2007, list, development, permissions

Trying to find a C# script that will list me all the groups of Current Web for sake of webpart that will show users the groups and users having permission to a specific web.

I know I can get all the users by following code,

```
foreach (SPUser user in SPContext.Current.Web.Users)
            {
}
```

but then how can I actually access the Permissions List and then Access the properties of the Items.

I find this relevant webpart which is related to what I want but, **its listing all the webs a user have access to, In my case I want to List all the Users/Groups have access to the Site**

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will give you the groups and the users in the groups.

```
foreach (SPGroup group in SPContext.Current.Web.Groups)
{
    foreach (SPUser user in group.Users)
    {

    }
}
```

Additionally, there is SPWeb.AllUsers wich represents all users who are members of the web or who have browsed to the site because they have access via a domain group.

SPWeb.Users only gives you the users that have been added to the web explicity (i.e. outside the comfort of a SharePoint or domain group).

Comment: +1 for the difference between AllUsers and Users